# GroupbyKey on spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, sparkcore

Does groupByKey causes a shuffle of all values across the network, even if they are already co-located within a partition, When we do group by operation in sparkSQL , does it uses groupbykey or it uses aggregateByKey for performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupByKey` will not shuffle on data if the keys are all co-located within each partition. But that would be a rare case.

`groupBy` operation in `sparkSQL` is an `aggregateByKey` which makes it an aggregation operation. We can define aggregation functions after `groupBy` in `sparkSQL`. `groupBy` simply create one instance of the `Aggregation Expressions` for each group and each aggregation and go through the data and keep updating those Expressions